# Log on with two accounts on SSH with one port?

Tags: ssh, vps

I'm wondering if logging into SSH on the same VPS using the same port will cause some issues with my server.  After attempting to log in with the second user, I now cannot log in with the default user.  PuTTY keeps saying `Network error: connection timed out`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not cause an issue.  This issue was caused by the VPS host having changed my password without my knowledge.